# Does an ObservableCollection bind easily outside of the WPF framework?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am making my first attempt at applying the MVVM pattern and have made it to the point in my application where I need to bind the data to the UI. A couple of articles that I have read mentioned breaking the final visible data down into the most common datatypes possible (eg. int, string, bool). I currently have some data grids bound to ObservableCollection objects and I am struggling to find where the line on "Common enough" data types are.

Should I look into breaking my objects down into more simple data types or would it not be worth the effort?

One of the reasons for choosing to use a MVVM pattern in this project is because we may want to switch to Xamarin in the future for mobile UIs.

Please note that I (currently) only have experience with WPF.

Comment: When you have Grids you tend to incline to use ObservableCollection. Reason being auto change notification for data property changes.

Comment: _"A couple of articles that I have read..."_ -- don't believe everything you read on the Internet. And make sure that if you think what you read is offering advice that doesn't make sense, that you read it again to make sure it's saying what you thought it's saying. You haven't referenced the specific articles, but I'm skeptical that they provide any sort of advice that would warn against using `ObservableCollection` in a WPF or other XAML-based program.

Comment: Thank you all for the insight. It seems my concern stems from a fundamental misunderstanding of the WPF framework. I formed the incorrect assumption that the simple data types used in beginner examples (like the one [here](https://riptutorial.com/wpf/example/992/basic-mvvm-example-using-wpf-and-csharp) would also need to be used to be able to bind controls in other UI frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I look into breaking my objects down into more simple data types or would it not be worth the effort?

No. Keep the `Model`s based on the database or webservice call and keep them at that.

I would only distill them down, if there is a specific need, such as extrapolating a property between multiple properties.

Keep in mind that MVVM is not a religion, its a fancier way of providing a separation of concerns from the view, the data and the database/Service. It used to be called "3-tiered architecture" back in the day.

> grids bound to ObservableCollection objects

Binding will work with just plain lists. One only has to use `ObservableCollections` if items are dynamically being added or removed from that collection. Then a notification is sent to inform a control that binds to that collection to update from the changed collection.

But if the collection will not change for the lifetime scope of the operation, keep it a plain generic `List`.

---

I provide a basic example of MVVM and databinding (without `ObeservableCollections`) which might help your understanding:

[Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017)